# ArrayList Updating Automatically in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, mvvm, viewmodel

I have passed same ArrayList in two method separately and set them two separate ArrayList in ViewModel. When I am updating one (names) ArrayList  but another (initialNames) ArrayList also updating. Why this is happening ? What can I do for this so that initialNames will not update ?

class DetailsFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentDetailsBinding

private var nameList:ArrayList<Name>? = null

private val detailsViewModel by viewModels<DetailsViewModel> (factoryProducer = {
    object : ViewModelProvider.Factory{
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            val database = LocalDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())!!
            val invoiceRepository = NameRepository(database)
            return DetailsViewModel(invoiceRepository) as T
        }
    }
})


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        nameList = it.getParcelableArrayList("NAME")
    }
}




override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    binding = FragmentDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    nameList?.let {
        detailsViewModel.setInitialName(it)
        detailsViewModel.setName(it)
    }

    binding.btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {

        detailsViewModel.updateList()

        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()

    }

    return binding.root
}
```

}

class DetailsViewModel (private val nameRepository: NameRepository): ViewModel(){

```
private var names = arrayListOf<Name>()
private var initialNames = arrayListOf<Name>()

var name = MutableStateFlow<String>("")


fun setName(names:ArrayList<Name>){
    this.names = names
}

fun setInitialName(names:ArrayList<Name>){
    this.initialNames = names
}


fun updateList(){

    Log.d(TAG, "updateList: $initialNames") //Here list is same as first time set.

    for (name in names){
        if (name.id == 2){
            name.name = "New Name"
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "updateList: $initialNames") //Here list changed.

}
```

}

Comment: You passed the same list instance to both of your ViewModel functions. So both properties in the ViewModel are pointing at the same list.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code in fragment

`detailsViewModel.setInitialName(it)`
`val newList = it.map { it.copy() }`
`detailsViewModel.setName(ArrayList(newList))`

this way I solved my problem .